# XAMPP Control Panel: eror

Tags: server, xampp, web, webserver

I am new to xamp. When I start Appache then the following error shows up:

```
23:19:08  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
23:19:08  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
23:19:08  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
23:19:08  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
23:19:08  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
23:19:08  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
23:19:08  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Did you check/try ANY of the information given in that output? There may be clues to be found! This has been a relatively common question here, and the reasons vary widely, so search this site too.

Comment: I solved the problem: i had to change the port to 81 instead of 80

Answer (score 0):

From what I've learned recently for Window's users, you can solve the problem by going to the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.

Right-click on the server name and select "Stop"

I'm not so sure but I've tried and it works for me.  Here's a screenshot of where to right-click in IIS Manager:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Loi-Wai, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  I appreciate your attempt to provide an answer to this (quite old) question. I'd like to offer some advice on why this [probably wasn't a great one to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) -- First, the question didn't really belong on Stack Overflow to begin with, since it isn't related to a *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problem."*  Second, the original poster had already found an answer and placed it in the comments (which wasn't the proper thing to do either - It should have been provided as an answer itself).

Comment: That said, your answer *is* valid, but I would recommend that you attempt to provide *why* this works as part of the answer.  Hint (if you need it) -- It works for the same reason that changing the port from 80 to 81 worked for the OP in the comments.

Comment: Finally, fix the "enter image description here".  When you get just a few reputation points, you'll be able to make it inline.  I'll submit an edit to do that part, though.